# Mockito not giving back the expected value

Tags: spring-boot, mockito

I created a unit test for a function but when it comes to find the entity from flatRepository it gives back:

> me.flatkeepr.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Flat 1 not found
>
> at
>   me.flatkeepr.service.TaskService.lambda$create$2(TaskService.java:54)
>     at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:408)  at
>   me.flatkeepr.service.TaskService.create(TaskService.java:54)

How this should work?

What I tried so far:
- added @Mock annotation
- put MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this) into the init function
- put Optional.of in the return value

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TaskServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private final TaskRepository taskRepository = Mockito.mock(TaskRepository.class);

    @Mock
    private final FlatRepository flatRepository = Mockito.mock(FlatRepository.class);

    @Mock
    private final UserRepository userRepository = Mockito.mock(UserRepository.class);

    @InjectMocks
    private TaskService taskService;



    @Test
    public void createTaskWithNoDeadLine() {
        TaskDTO fresh = new TaskDTO();
        fresh.setName("Clean up");
        fresh.setScore(10);
        fresh.setDescription("Short summary");

        Flat flat = new Flat();
        flat.setName("Flat");

        Task task = TaskMapper.INSTANCE.convertToEntity(fresh);
        task.setId(1L);

        when(taskRepository.existsByNameAndFlatId(fresh.getName(), 1L)).thenReturn(false);
        when(flatRepository.findById(1L)).thenReturn(Optional.of(flat));
        when(taskRepository.save(task)).thenReturn(task);

        TaskDTO actual = taskService.create(1L, fresh);


        assertEquals("Clean up", actual.getName());
        assertEquals(10, actual.getScore().intValue());
        assertEquals("Short summary", actual.getDescription());
    }
}
```

The function in service layer:

```
public create(Long flatId, TaskDTO fresh) {
return flatRepository.findById(flatId).map(flat -> {
                Task task = createEntity(fresh);
                task.setId(null);
                task.setFlat(flat);
                return createDTO(taskRepository.save(task));
            }).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Flat " + flatId + " not found"));
}
```

Comment: Since you already initialise the mocks with `Mockito.mock(...)` your annotations and the call to `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` are redundant.

Comment: Okay, I removed that, but the issue still is there :/

Comment: As you are using JUnit, make use of the `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` then you can have the `@Mock` annotations and also annotate `@InjectMocks private TaskService taskService` then remove the `init()` altogether - everything will be initialised for you by the runner. 
p.s.  you also need to remove the ` = Mockito.mock(...);` initialisers - they are not needed when `@Mock` annotations are in use.

Comment: Added. Still no luck

Comment: Have you tried debugging the `flatRepository.findById(flatId)` to see what is being returned. It could be your stubbing behaviour that's not ok. 
I'd go for `when(flatRepository.findById(eq(1L))).thenReturn(Optional.of(flat));` rather than direct `1L` parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved my question:

Instead of this:

```
return createDTO(taskRepository.save(task));
```

I should write this:

```
taskRepository.save(task);
return createDTO(task);
```

Now it pass the test

Comment: However, note that the behaviour of your code is now different. You are constructing the DTO from the original `task` instance, not the one returned by the repository call.  Depending on what the repository does with it, the semantics of your code may have completely changed. 
I suggest that you go through the stubbing to make the test pass with the original code and also think carefully if the change you made is acceptable and does not create hidden bugs.

Comment: Yes I found that too, but the problem is with the flatRepository mocking because it doesn't return the expected value.